# mootools variable scope

Tags: mootools

how to access outer function's argument 'parent' ??? **please see comments in code
!!**
**last edit : This question is misleading, my problem is caused by wrong input argument**

```
renderData : function(parent, children){
            children.each(function(e, index){
                var li = new Element('li');
                var hasChildren = false;
                if(e.children && e.children.length >0){
                    var img = new Element('img');
                    img.src = 'a1.png';
                    img.inject(li);
                    hasChildren = true;
                }
                if(e.icon){
                    var img = new Element('img');
                    img.src = e.icon;
                    img.inject(li);
                }else{
                    var img = new Element('img');
                    img.src = 'b1.png';
                    img.inject(li);
                }
                li.set('html',e.text);
                console.log(this);
                     // how to access outer function's argument 'parent' ???
                li.inject(parent);
                if(hasChildren){
                    var ul = new Element('ul');
                    this.renderData(ul, e.childRen);
                    ul.inject(e);
                }
            }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within an each loop:

```
array.each(function(el) {
    this.method(); // this == (instance / scope)
}, this); // where **this** is your parent scope.
```

another acceptable way is:

```
var self = this;
...
array.each(function(el) {
    self.method(); // fine.
}); // where this is your parent scope.
```

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array:Array-each

although, using `.bind(this)` should work too... http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/fFy4J/ - so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

if i understood correctly, your problem is that you cant do `li.inject(parent)`

there's no reason why you can't access 'parent' since it's been passed as a parameter to the function `renderData()`

I've tried this [simple test](http://jsfiddle.net/hP5j5/)

```
var test;
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
      test = new TestClass();
 });

var TestClass = new Class({
    Implements: [Options, Events],
    initialize: function(){
        this.renderData($('parent'),$$('span'))
    },

    renderData : function(parent, children){
          children.each(function(e, index){
                console.log(parent);
            }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

and it works fine... but i'm no really sure what's the problem on your code

Comment: sorry guys, caused by another problem.